# How to get days difference between two dates in velocity templates?

Tags: velocity

I want to get days difference between today's date and a payment due date (next date greater than  todays date) using velocity template. If my today date is `12/10/2016(MM/dd/yyy)` and payment date is `22/10/2016(MM/dd/yyy)`,the date difference should be `10`. I tried in difference ways, couldn not find the exact solution. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Are you passing the dates at some sort of date object? If so, which one? Or are you passing them to Velocity as Strings?

Comment: i am passing dates into velocity as strings

Comment: If you pass them to your template as date objects, then you can use methods of the whichever date class you use. E.g. `$myDateObj.compareTo($myOtherDateObject)` could be used to compare 2 Calendar objects. Using Strings with this would be quite difficult.

Comment: i tried with this but the compareTo is not seems to be working. I am taking this string date from a consumer object in java classand want to compare this date  with the todays date and need to get the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *velocity-tools*, you can check the [ComparisonDateTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html).

Answer (score 1):

`$dateTool.getDate()` is todays date.

Final statement is like so:

```
$date.difference($payDate, $dateTool.getDate()).days==10
```

Make sure you have `ComparisonDateTool` in *tools.xml*.

```
class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ComparisonDateTool"
              format="MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s" depth="1" skip="month,week"
              bundle="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.times" timezone="EST"/>
```